# PHP wont echo into Iframe in Webkit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, webkit

hey guys I'm having a problem with an upload form I've made. It works in Firefox and IE but it wont work with Safari and Chrome so I assume it's a webkit problem.
First I run the php form and change the target to an iframe. Then once it's finished uploading I get PHP to echo a div iwth a statement true/false back into the iframe.
The problem i'm having is that PHP isn't echoing the statement into the iframe.
here's the code i've got:

in the php:

```
    //do all the appropriate checks etc and if it's uploaded do the following

    if ($success == true)
    {
       echo '<div id="result">success</div>';
    } else {
       echo '<div id="result">error</div>';
    }
```

then in my javascript I do a few checks to see if the forms filled out etc and then if all is well I call submit() first and then I call iframeCheck()

```
    function submit()
{

    //change the target of the upload form to upload to the iframe.
    $('#contactForm').attr('target','uploadIframe');
    //submit the iframe
    $('#contactForm').submit();
    //fade in the sending message
    $('#sendingMessage').fadeIn(200);

}

function iframeCheck()
{
    //get the contents of iframe
    var elem = $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('div#result');
    var result = elem.html();
    //if there's nothing in it, upload hasn't finished...
    if ( elem.length <= 0)
    {
        //check it again in 2"
        clearTimeout(timer);
        var timer = setTimeout(iframeCheck, 2000);
    } else if (result =='success'){
        //if it contains a success message, display the success message
        $('#sendingMessage').fadeOut(200);
        $('#successMessage').fadeIn(500);
         inputButton.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        if (result == 'error')
        {
            //otherwise display the error message
            $('#sendingMessage').fadeOut(200);
            $('#failureMessage').fadeIn(500);
             inputButton.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine in ff and IE but as i said chrome and safari wont echo into the iframe.
Thanks for your help folks!

Comment: hey man, php is server side so it shouldnt matter what browser youre using.  problems i  your client side script.

Comment: if that demo works, then it is not browser problem: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: why not use $.post() $.get() ? in such case ?

Comment: I don't really know the cause, but just wanted to point out that your clearTimeout will never do anything since timer is scoped within iframeCheck.

Comment: I originally used $.ajax() which is just shorthand for $.post() and $.get() isn't it? It didn't work though because it was timing out or something. This was the best way I could find for an asynchronous file upload. @logan, I thought the clearTimeout would work because it's called within iframeCheck and the scope of var timer is within iframeCheck. could be wrong though.

Comment: You'd need `var timer;` outside and `timer = setTimeout(...);` inside of iframeCheck if you want the value of "timer" to be preserved between calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks heaps for your guys help. John it was a problem with my javascript. I was disabling the send button as soon as it was clicked. This worked fine except that webkit didn't like it so what I had to do was add onsubmit="document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled=true;" and that works fine now.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is the iFrame URL the same domain as the general homepage? Perhaps it has something todo with cross domain policy.

Comment: I have just lef the src attribute blank because i only want the contents of the iframe to be the div with the reply in it. Would changing this url help you think?

Comment: I don't really know if that helps. What I wrote just came into my mind when reading your problem.